# Exec SQL Server 2012 package on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have packages in SQL Server 2012 SSIS format. I need to run it on a Windows Server 2003 server, which has SQL Server 2008 installed. I copied `Dtexec.exe` and `dtexec.exe.config` files to the server and run

```
dtexec /f mypackage.dtsx
```

However, the program quit without any error message. What should I do to enable it running on SQL Server 2008 / Windows Server 2003 ?

Comment: Does the program quite each time you attempt to run it?  Sounds like the SSIS package includes functions and requirements (perhaps Framework 4.0) that are not backwards compatible.  Have you tried opening the the SSIS package in SQL Server 2008 R2 Business Intelligence Studio on the Windows 2003 server to see if it identifies the specific problems?

Comment: You are going to need so many more files than that (i.e. DLL's). That kind of thing just doesn't work any more - you need to install the whole thing, and therefore go through the doco on installing side by side installs if SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-create the package using BIDS. SQL Server Data Tools has introduced new features in SSIS that are not available in the older BIDS version(s).